Indication of the mouse button status when Mouse Keys is enabled
When I enable Mouse Keys, I want an icon that shows this, similar to CentOS. Additionally, I want the icon to provide feedback on which mouse button I clicked (left, right, or middle). Is this possible in Ubuntu?
